# std::set custom comparator for non null strings

Tags: c++, c++17

As the title suggests am trying to implement comparison functor for my defined structure. Here is the sample snippet

```
#include<set>

struct testData
{
  char * data;
  int size;
};

class compare
{
public:
  bool operator()(const testData & lhs,
          const testData & rhs) const noexcept
  {
        
    return memcmp(lhs.data, rhs.data, lhs.size<rhs.size?lhs.size:rhs.size) < 0;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::set<testData,compare>S;

  ....
  return 0;
}
```

> Issue in the comparison function is since am taking lesser size,this
> case fails
>
> suppose there is already this data present {"test",4},and i am trying
> to find {"test1",5}.it will say as matched.How can i modify comparison
> to overcome this?

Update:

changed to this

```
class compare
{
public:
  bool operator()(const testData & lhs,
          const testData & rhs) const noexcept
  {
        if (lhs.size == rhs.size)
      return memcmp(lhs.data, rhs.data, lhs.size) < 0;

    return lhs.size < rhs.size;
  }
};
```

will this work?

Comment: You should write your own custom logic for comparing two `testData`. The fact that it's used in `set` is completely irrelevant. `memcmp` is not enough. `strcmp` probably will fail as well as is works with ASCIIZ strings. `for` loop should help.

Comment: `lhs.size<rhs.size?lhs.size:rhs.size` is more clearly expressed as `std::min(lhs.size, rhs.size)`

Answer (score 2):

You'd use [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.

```
class compare
{
public:
  bool operator()(const testData & lhs,
          const testData & rhs) const noexcept
  {
        
    return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.data, lhs.data + lhs.size, rhs.data, rhs.data + rhs.size);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason it failes is because you compare only the length of the smaller string.

In your example only the `"test"` part of `"test1"` will be compared.
You can try this:

```
bool operator()(const testData & lhs,
              const testData & rhs) const noexcept
      {
        int ret = memcmp(lhs.data, rhs.data, lhs.size<rhs.size?lhs.size:rhs.size);
    
        return  ret == 0 ? lhs.size < rhs.size : ret < 0 ;
      }
```

Comment: Agree, but would do the `size` test first as it can work to skip the `memcmp` if it doesn't match which could be _significantly_ faster.

Comment: its true that it would be faster but i dont know if it would be correct. for example for `char *s1 = "asdasd";` and `char *s2 = "bsd";`. comparing sizes first will say s1 > s2, but doing memcmp first will say that s2 > s1 (since 'b' > 'a')

Comment: Yeah, _strict weak ordering_ rules must apply and in this case you're right.  I try to avoid `string` (or `string`-like) keys because they can be a performance killer